# How to loop object value in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, oop, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an object named **Item.java** which is i have set the value like this:

this is my controller class. I named it HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    public HomeController(){

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        List<Item> ListItem = new ArrayList<Item>();

        ListItem.add(new Item("1","Pencil"));
        ListItem.add(new Item("2","Paper"));
        return "item";
    }

}
```

how to print out the object value in my Thymeleaf HTML page?

here is what i do :

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>Unique Item Code</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="mItem : ${Item}">
            <td><label type="text"
                    th:text="${mItem.code}" /></td>
            <td><label type="text"
                    th:text="${mItem.name}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>                            
</table>
```

Why is it not showing anything? Since I can't debug the HTML page, I just can debug my Java class, which is already has some value in it.

Comment: Could you include the complete code for the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the items to the model in the controller method like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    List<Item> ListItem = new ArrayList<Item>();

    ListItem.add(new Item("1","Pencil"));
    ListItem.add(new Item("2","Paper"));

    model.addAttribute("Item", ListItem); // This is important

    return "item";
}
```

By the way, your variable names don't follow standard Java naming conventions. I suggest to rename them (e.g. `ListItem` should be named something like `items`, The `Item` attribute you are passing to the view should be `items`, etc).